# Are active styluses (for tablets) generally compatible across OEMs?

Tags: graphics-tablet

I'm shopping for a new PC for school, and I'm really looking at tablet 2-in-1's. I want to have an active stylus to take notes on in class, and I've found a really good tablet from Acer (Aspire Switch Alpha 12, if you're interested), but I've heard that the pen is sub-par.

I know that many 2-in-1 makers (like Dell, HP, Lenovo, Acer, etc) use the same general technology to make their active pens work, but does anyone know if you could actually use a pen from a different OEM than the one you got your tablet from?

Again, this is kind of a broad question, so I just want to know if anyone has had success doing it at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of asking if something is compatible, try asking for a stylus that works with the Acer and give us any more requirements that you might have (like price and battery life).